# Why cards installment mentioned on the Diversified Portfolio?

Tags: android-netrunner

The [Diversified Portfolio](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05026) says: "Gain 1 credit for each remote server with a card installed in it". I wonder why the installment is mentioned in the text? There is no a remote server without cards installed in it. Can I have a remote server without cards installed in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have a remote server without cards **in** it if it's an empty server, but has ICE protecting it. The server exists, but doesn't qualify for Diversified Portfolio

Comment: Oh, I see. The ice installed "in front of the server", but all other cards are installed "in the server"? So, this terminology does metter. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, although I believe FFG always use "portecting the server" for ICE instead of "in front of the server". It also matters for cards like Singularity - it doesn't trash ICE protecting the server, only contents of it.

Answer (score 1):

A remote server exists when there are cards installed in it or there are cards installed protecting it. Ice is installed protecting a server, assets, agendas and upgrades are installed in a server. Portfolio ignores servers that are ice only as there is nothing inside the server, just in front of it.